# How can we log backbone history stack list in javascript mobile application?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I am developing android hybrid app using the backbone js framework. 
Does anyone know how to log or alert backbone history stack items in jquery or javascript?

```
Backbone.history function in backbone js.
```

Help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by overriding `Backbone.history.navigate` method:

```
var history = [];
var originalNavigate = Backbone.history.navigate;
Backbone.history.navigate = function (fragment) {
  history.push(fragment);
  return originalNavigate.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

All navigation history will be stored in the `history` array.